# (#ifdef) vs. (#define <boolean>)

Tags: c, preprocessor-directive

I am trying to figure out which practice is the best between :

```c
#define TEST 
//#define TEST commented if not used or simply deleted
```

```c
#define TEST 1
#define TEST 0 //if not used
```

For readability, I prefer to define a "Boolean" and check it in a `if` but I guess it is not efficient since it doesn't use `#ifdef` and it needs to be checked everytime in a if

Comment: While you can't use an `#ifdef` for your second case, you absolutely **can** use an `#if` so there would be no additional runtime cost for TEST 0. This btw. also means you can have multiple different values for TEST, maybe corresponding to different log levels or things like that

Comment: This is exactly the case I can have. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @FelixG: Put in an answer so the OP can accept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can't use an `#ifdef` for your second case, you absolutely can use an `#if` so there would be no additional runtime cost for TEST 0. This btw. also means you can have multiple different values for TEST, maybe corresponding to different log levels or things like that

(Posted my comment as an answer, as suggested by Bathsheba)

Answer (score 2):

Many moons ago some compilers (one for Solaris if I recall correctly) would not correctly compile code that used the first snippet.

But the C standard (now) requires them to and as such there is no benefit at all in using the second way which could now be regarded as idiosyncratic.

Of course if you need `TEST` to be a numerical value such as in a condition check as opposed to merely using `#ifdef` then you'd need to use the second way.

Comment: An additional benefit to the first way is that toolchains allow you to define constants externally; generally, using "-DDEBUG" to enable debug options without having to modify files.

Comment: That's some >400 moons ago so I'm not sure it is relevant. Also, early Solaris machines probably had a BFM instruction that newer computers lack (Branch on Full Moon).

Comment: *Many moons ago some compilers (one for Solaris if I recall correctly)*  Probably pre-C89, so "many moons" is 30+ years ago.  I remember when the "ANSI" standard came out, the `-ansi` argument to the Sun compiler would break a lot of preexisting code.

Comment: @Lundin, Only 10 years ago in a large investment bank I had to support a compiler that required the second way so I believe it's still relevant enough to indicate the possibility here. I left before the compiler was changed.